# Laravel 5.2 save relations on model save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a User model with two relations :

```
//User model

function profile() {
   return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}

public function photos() {
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

I would like to save relations data when creating the user.

The idea is to send an Event before saving the user, and change some relation data

something like this :

```
$profile = new Profile;
$profile->fill($profileData); // I don't want to persist it right now

$photos = [];
foreach ($photosData as $photoData) {
    $photo = new Photo;
    $photo->fill($photoData);
    $photos[] = $photo;
}

$user = new User;
$user->data = "data";

$user->profile() // Do something
$user->photos() // Do something

event(new UserWillBeCreated($user));

$user->save(); // this will create in database Profile, Photos and user
```

And in the listener of my event, I can update profile data if I want before saving

```
  $user->profile->name = "another name";
```

Comment: do you want to save `$user->profile()` in event listener?

Comment: no I would like to save it when I execute `$user->save()`

Comment: What is not working in your current idea?

Comment: You'll need to save the user first, in order for it to have an `id` or other primary key you are using to make the relation possible.

Comment: This was something always on my mind too, but I always used another solution to problems. I am interested in knowing the answer too :)